# Debian cannot connect to local daemons from localhost

Tags: debian

Long story short.

> Apache2 running on 0.0.0.0:80
>
> Mysqld running on 0.0.0.0:3306

Can't access these ports from localhost, but CAN access them from remote hosts.

From Remote host (laptop)

```
MacBook-Pro:~ codemaster$ telnet 192.168.0.10 3306
Trying 192.168.0.10...
Connected to 192.168.0.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
T
5.5.40-0+wheezy1/QmQ,%uA?0b|m+.BDn|G*mysql_native_password^CConnection closed by foreign host.
MacBook-Pro:~ codemaster$ telnet 192.168.0.10 80
Trying 192.168.0.10...
Connected to 192.168.0.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

From Localhost (192.168.0.10)

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# uname -a
Linux udoo-debian-hfp 3.0.35 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 3 15:17:07 CET 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# netstat -a -n -p|grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21469/mysqld    
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# netstat -a -n -p|grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3614/apache2    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3880     3763/dbus-daemon    

root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:08:88:a1:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:956650 (934.2 KiB)  TX bytes:644410 (629.3 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7e:82:37:77:b9:01  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:dd:90:3a:4a:a6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Tried several options, hangs on 'trying to connect'

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# telnet 192.168.0.10 80
Trying 192.168.0.10...
^C
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# telnet 192.168.0.10 3306
Trying 192.168.0.10...
^C
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
^C
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
^C
```

No IPTABLES

```
root@udoo-debian-hfp:/# iptables -L
FATAL: Module ip_tables not found.
iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Never met with something like this before... Either it was iptables blocking or daemons bound to the local interface.. but local to local?

Comment: Is your loopback interface up? Try `ip link set lo up`.

Comment: Amazing - job done.
Celada - post as an answer please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like your loopback interface isn't up. The loopback interface (IPv4 127.0.0.1/8, IPv6 ::1/128) is necessary for communications from one host to the same host.

On Debian, the loopback interface is normally turned up at boot time with the following configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I don't know why your loopback interface didn't come up properly but try `ifup lo` (managed, preferred) or `ip link set lo up` (unmanaged) and also make sure the above lines are present in `/etc/network/interfaces`.